# How can I construct a percentage of my objects as female?

Tags: java, repast-simphony

I have an agent class that does things:

```
public class Agent {


private Context<Object> context;
    private Geography<Object> geography;
    public int id;
    boolean female;

public Agent(Context<Object> context, Geography<Object> geography, int id, boolean female) {
    this.id = id;
    this.context = context;
    this.geography = geography;
    this.female = female;
}  

... setters getters
... do things methods

}
```

In the context builder class, where my agents are added into the context (geographic space composed of latitude and longitude coordinates), I want to make a random percentage of my Agents female (female = true).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Agent agent = new Agent(context, geography, i, false);
        int id = i++;
        if(id > 50) {
            boolean female = true;  
        }
        context.add(agent);
        //specifies where to add the agent
        Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(-79.6976, 43.4763);
        Point geom = fac.createPoint(coord);
        geography.move(agent, geom);
    }
```

I believe the code above constructs the last 50 agents as female. How can I make it so they are randomly created as female? I change the number of agents created quite a bit.

Comment: [`Random#nextBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your code, you ALWAYS create an agent that is MALE.

try to evaluate if it's female before creating an instance of `Agent`:

```
Agent agent = null;
boolean isFemale = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int id = i++;
        if(id > 50) {
            isFemale = true;
        }
        agent = new Agent(context, geography, i, isFemale);
        context.add(agent);
        //specifies where to add the agent
        Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(-79.6976, 43.4763);
        Point geom = fac.createPoint(coord);
        geography.move(agent, geom);
    }
```

if you want it random, try using Random utility:

```
        Random random = new Random();
        agent = new Agent(context, geography, i, random.nextBoolean());
```

hope this helps

Comment: `agent = new Agent(context, geography, i, isFemale);` can be moved outside of the if and else statements.

Comment: and then you can remove isFemale altogether by doing: agent = new Agent(context, geography, i, id>50);

Comment: I'm good with that. That's based on the OP's code anyway. the OP can optimize it further =)

Comment: and chances are that you can move coord = ... and geom = ... outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single instance of Random outside your for loop and use random.nextBoolean() as a parameter for your boolean female attribute of agent().

Answer (score -1):

```
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            boolean isFemale = (random.Next(2) % 2 == 1);
            ...
        }
```